# unable to resolve dependency tree error when using npm install generic-ui

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I was trying to install generic-ui in my angular project using the cmd:

```
npm i @generic-ui/ngx-grid @generic-ui/fabric @generic-ui/hermes
```

but I got the following error :

```
$ npm i @generic-ui/ngx-grid @generic-ui/fabric @generic-ui/hermes
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: angular-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@13.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"~13.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"12.2.11" from @generic-ui/ngx-grid@0.16.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@generic-ui/ngx-grid
npm ERR!   @generic-ui/ngx-grid@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PC\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-10T20_30_51_751Z-debug-0.log
```

I literally tried everything, I updated npm, installed Angular CLI again, downloaded and installed node again, npm audit, and a lot of other things but nothing happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are trying to install @angular/common@13.1.3 in your project but the module @generic-ui/ngx-grid@0.16.4 ask the package @angular/common@"12.2.11" is not yet compatible

in the github page of ngx-grid it says the module is not yet compatible with angular 13

> Currently highest supported Angular version is 12.2. We are working on
> bringing Gui libraries to Angular 13.

https://github.com/generic-ui/generic-ui

The better for your project it to stay to angular 12 while dependencies are not compatible with angular 13